# Unable to enter Full values using Selenium Script, only half of the values are passed in to the field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am trying to enter a text into an "unselectable row" sometimes it enters only half of the text (it fails to enter first few Characters)

E.g:
If I am trying to enter "qqwwssagsdafdsagdfgafgafdahdghjagds" text, sometimes it accepts only last few characters i.e. fgafdahdghjagds.

HTML code of the element which i am trying to enter Values:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ext-comp-1002" class="x-layer x-editor x-small-editor x-grid-editor" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; overflow: auto; width: 238px;">
<input id="mltprcrtmain-1" class=" x-form-text x-form-field x-form-fieldui x-form-field-text " type="edit" name="mltprcrtmain-1" autocomplete="off" size="20" style="width: 238px;" maxlength="32">
```

Script which i have used to pass values in unselectable row (i.e.row) :

**Code:**

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id(genericHandlingExcel.getdata(FilePath, Sheetname2, 66,2)))).click(); 
act.sendKeys(genericHandlingExcel.getdata(FilePath, Sheetname2, 66,3)); 
Thread.sleep(5000);
act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: HTMl code of the element which i am trying to enter Values:

<div id="ext-comp-1002" class="x-layer x-editor x-small-editor x-grid-editor" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; overflow: auto; width: 238px;">
<input id="mltprcrtmain-1" class=" x-form-text x-form-field x-form-fieldui x-form-field-text " type="edit" name="mltprcrtmain-1" autocomplete="off" size="20" style="width: 238px;" maxlength="32">

Comment: Script which i have used to pass values in unselectable row (i.e. row) :                                                        
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
  act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id(genericHandlingExcel.getdata(FilePath, Sheetname2, 66,2)))).click();
  act.sendKeys(genericHandlingExcel.getdata(FilePath, Sheetname2, 66,3));
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Comment: Please add code in question, not in comment

Comment: You should add an appropriate tag for the language that you're using, and [edit] the question to include the code you're using.

Comment: As seeing your html code input tag have size attribute which limits your input in this field .

Comment: Can you check the entered value manually? Values may be entered correctly and only last portion of characters might be visible in UI. Can you please check and confirm once?

Answer (score 1):

As per your input HTML, your input text box size is 20 and it will support maximum of 32 characters.So, we should able to enter only max of 32 characters and only few characters will be visible in UI(At Max, 20 characters will be displayed and it may be changed based on the attribute which is mentioned in the class).

You are trying to enter a text with 35 characters and hence few characters might not be entered correctly

I would suggest to validate the entered character manually and also ensure the same by manually entering the same character.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a small pause in code after click:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver); 
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id(genericHandlingExcel.getdata(FilePath, Sheetname2, 66,2)))).click();
Thread.sleep(2000); // add a small pause after click
act.sendKeys(genericHandlingExcel.getdata(FilePath, Sheetname2, 66,3)); 
Thread.sleep(5000); 
act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```